# AChartEngine - textlabel ignores padding

Tags: android, achartengine

When adding text labels to either axis, they seem to ignore any padding specified. I.e. the label text is drawn right next to the axis.

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    mRenderer.addYTextLabel(i, "test");
}
mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20);
```

The padding works for numeric values, but not for text labels. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: I've created a work-around by adding spaces to the end of the strings which works fine.